# Generate random codes that are decrypted by the same algorithm

Tags: android, vb.net, encryption

I want to make a code that generated random sequence numbers or text/numbers and the generated code can be decrypted by one application and get the same output. In other words i want to generate these random codes and use them for activating a product. So the user will need to contact me to send him a generated code, and he will use that code on the application(android) and it will let him login. So many generated codes will work on the same app. An example that comes to my mind is the Blizzard authenticator. It generates many keys and the user can insert any of those keys to login.

I would like to implement a vb.net code to generate keys and an algorith on android to decrypt them and get a valid output. 
Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encryption is a funny thing. What you want to achieve is encryption of an arbitrary string, which could just as well be

```
MyApp version 3.5 serial no #434376
```

You can encode this as stated above, but then everyone would plainly understand that and be able to modify it.
You could translate that to some little known language thus eliminating pretty much all of the rest of the world, but unless the numbers were further encoded, everyone would still be able to modify them. A simple trial-and-error would soon provide results for wannabe pirates.

Or you could encode it in some cypher you just made up, e.g.

```
CAC53X673434
```

Here CAC stands for "My app", X stands for "serial no #" and all the numbers are reversed.

This is all fine and dandy, but you still don't have any security. Any user can change any of those numbers at any time and your app will still register such a serial as valid (as long as it's the right length and contains CAC and X and both numbers).

That's when you also add a [checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum) such as [CRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) at the end of the code:

```
CAC53X673434FG
```

The FG in this case is some checksum calculated from the preceding string. Your serial generator can calculate this checksum and your app can generate it as well. The app just does this additional check to see if the generator provided checksum matches what it calculated.

Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: very informative and helpful m8 thank you. Yes that's what i basically want. Do you also have any example in action? Or any links i can see with implementations?

Comment: Just look up CRC16 algorithm for your language of choice. Convert output of algorithm to hex (so that you end up with a nice ASCII string) and you're done.

Comment: thank you very much m8. Ill look that up. cheers